# TED for Joplin (to replace Evernote/Tusk)

Tags: text-editor, evernote

The intent here is to use Joplin as a note taking app to replace Evernote/Tusk .  However Joplin's editor is oriented for coders, whereas my needs are for a good RTF text editor.
A blog recommended TED.

Using Ubuntu Mate 20.04, with Joplin 1.7.11 ; I've downloaded TED ted-2.23-amd64.deb but the Deb Pkg Installer complains about a dependency not being satisfied for libtiff4.  The lintian output is:
*W: ted: hardening-no-pie usr/bin/Ted
Lintian finished with exit status 0*

Synpatic Pks Mngr reports the pkg to be broken, and won't let me remove it or re-install it.

[Appauls](https://appuals.com/fix-unable-correct-problems-held-broken-packages/) suggested to try:
*sudo dpkg --configure -a*
and
*sudo apt-get install -f*

. . . but to  no avail.  Then from the CLI and then Synaptics I tried to install libtiff4, removing it and re-installing but nothing works.

Any help appreciated, any other rtf editor suggestion also appreciated, and compatibility with Joplin more than appreciated.

Thx

xian

PS: please create a tag for Joplin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still can get `libtiff4` installed by manual download:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb

wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Also you need `libpng12`. For Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS it is installable from [special PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/libpng12) by commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libpng12-0
```

And then finally install the TED editor:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/editors/ted/ted-2.23-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./ted-2.23-amd64.deb
```

and then execute it by `Ted` or launch from *Applications → Office → Ted rtf text processor*.

---

Also please note that RTF is not version-control systems friendly.
So Markdown is better for this purpose. Apps to test may include [VNote](https://github.com/tamlok/vnote), [Notable](https://notable.app/), [BoostNote](https://boostnote.io/) and [DeepTags](https://github.com/SZinedine/DeepTags). For random notes without folder-file structure one can use [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/).